# why Sharing violation on path in Xamarin PCL

Tags: c#, multithreading, xamarin, static-methods, portable-class-library

Here is the complete error

> Sharing violation on path
>   /data/data/com.test.app/files/myapp/myappfile.txt

I am having static class and static having this method inside static method but the issue still happens

I tried wrapping this in lock statement but I'm not sure if it fixes the issue.Is there any better way to fix this problem

Here is the code snippet that causes the issue

```
            try
            {
                var directory = await NavigateToFolder(directoryName);
                IFile file = await directory.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
                await file.WriteAllTextAsync(text);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Error saving:" + e.Message);
            }
```

*FYI:*

- My project is Xamarin native project.
- I am using the code across my project

*Update:*

sometimes this code snippet corrupts the file.I get the following error if I try to write times.

> Could not find file
>   "/data/data/com.test.app/files/myapp/myappfile.txt"

Any helpful suggestions are welcome

Comment: What is IFile? Is it Disposable? Maybe you need to wrap it into `using` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct code. File system doesn't implement lock and accessing the file system is always error-prone, you must expect that the operation might fail and use try/catch to catch the exception.

As this is Xamarin app you probably have the luxury that only your app is expected to access the files, so eventually you may fix the problem inside the app. The best solution would depend on the context, but in most cases the best idea might be to use debouncing strategy (using `Timer` so that the critical method might not start more frequently than once in e.g. 100 ms).